# converting hardcode data into dynamic foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a hardcoded data that I wanted to convert and the problem I am having is the multi dimensional array and that causes me to fail here is the hardcoded :

```
$query = array(
    'No' => 'test123',
    'list' => array(
        0 => array(
            'title' => 'MR'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'title' => 'MS'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'title' => 'MISS'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'title' => 'MISS'
        ),
    ),
);
```

I tried converting to dynamic php foreach from the data like this :

```
  foreach($datas as $data) {
    $num = count($data);
    $newdata = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
      $dataid = $data[$i]['target_id'];
      $datainfo = dataget($dataid);
      $title = strtoupper($datainfo->title);

      $datalist[] = array(
            'title' => $title,
          );
    }
  }
  $query = array (
      'No' => $title,
      'list' => $datalist
  );
```

but its not working, when I submit more then 1 data, it is not working, but when it is only 1 data it is working.

am I doing the refactoring of code correctly? can someone please clarify?

thank you

Comment: your code has a lot of bugs, can you update with all codes, and $datas array?

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach use is incorrect. You are mixing data and datas.

```
foreach($datas as $data)
```

should be changed to

```
foreach($data as $datas)
```

Inside the loop, all occurrence of $data should change to $datas.

I didn't really get what you wanted to do clearly. But using the following code, I was able to print the content of the whole array.

```
$irr = array(
    'No' => 'test123',
    'list' => array(
        0 => array('title' => 'MR'),
        1 => array('title' => 'MS'),
        2 => array('title' => 'MISS'),
        3 => array('title' => 'MISS')
    ),
    'No2' => 'test2',
    'listo' => array(
        0 => array('title' => 'MR'),
        1 => array('title' => 'MS'),
        2 => array('title' => 'Mato')
    )
);

echo "<br>";
foreach($irr as $key=>$data) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($num == 1) { 
        echo $key . "=>" . $data."<br>";
        continue;
    }

    echo $key . "=> <br>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
      $dataid = $data[$i]['title'];
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$dataid."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry its an example as the real variable is not that should be the updated version, thank you